# Rails Console fails to run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-console

rbenv ruby version: **2.6.6**

rails version: **5.1.4**

I am working within an older codebase (ruby: 2.6.6 | rails: 5.4.1). This is a codebase I work with daily. I had to download a new ruby version, through rbenv, for a separate repo and in doing so caused quite an issue in my dev environment for the older codebase.

My initial investigation of the issue that popped up led me to delete the rbenv ruby version I had for the older code base (2.6.6), re-install the ruby version, rehash then reinstall bundler.

Previously, I could just run rails command (`rails c`, `rails s`) to open the console or run the server. Now I am met with this error when trying to run a rails command:

```
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.3.1
```

When trying to open the rails console with the following commands, `bundle exec rails console`, `bin/rails console`, I am met with this error:

```
`preload': Spring only supports Rails >= 5.2.0 (RuntimeError)
```

After running `bin/rails s`, and opening the webpage, the console returns a 500 error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 427ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)


Error during failsafe response: couldn't find file 'ckeditor/init' with type 'application/javascript'
```

Comment: Seems like you're running a `rails` executable that's older than your project's Rails version. Try `bin/rails console` or `bundle exec rails console`. (from within your project's root)

Comment: Both commands return the same error

Comment: That's odd. Can you provide some more details, please? Is this a new project or an existing one? Did it used to work? Did you update / change anything recently? (the project, Rails or maybe Ruby itself)

Comment: Can you post your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` ? This is not the answer but can you try stop spring and see if it works: `bundle exec spring stop`

Comment: I updated the description of the issue. Unfortunately, I cannot post the `Gemfile` or `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: You can add some extracts from your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, by using the ``` white space line + code + white space line ```. That will show the content fof your files in markdown format. Also, you can run `rails about` cmd, which show all the information related to the app code base.

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Answer (score -2):

This isn't the exact answer to your question, but the workaround I did for the "**Spring only supports Rails >= 5.2.0**" was to just create a new project with rails 5.2.3 or something.

If you want to do the same, you can first list all your local gems by doing `gem list rails --local`

You will see all your rails versions installed locally.

Then do `gem install rails -v '5.2.3'`

Now go to a new project directory and run `rails _5.2.3_ new appname`

Now, you should be able to use the console, generate, migrate and other commands.

You can do bundle install after adding other relevant gems based on your apps requirement.