# Spring is troubling rails console to start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spring-gem

When i am trying to execute:

```
bundle exec rails console
```

It is throwing me error as:

```
/gems/spring-3.1.1/lib/spring/application.rb:96:in `preload': Spring only supports Rails >= 5.2.0 (RuntimeError)
```

Earlier it was working fine.
Can anyone help me with a workaround for this.

Comment: someone asked this question with similar issue here which is not yet answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270436/rails-console-fails-to-run

Answer (score -1):

The workaround I did for this was to create a new project with rails 5.2.3 or something.

If you want to do the same, you can first list all your local gems by doing `gem list rails --local`

You will see all your rails versions installed locally.

Then do `gem install rails -v '5.2.3'`

Now go to a new project directory and run `rails _5.2.3_ new appname`

Now, you should be able to use the console, generate, migrate and other commands.

You can do `bundle install` after adding other relevant gems based on your apps requirement.